# Is it always true that a laminar boundary layer will always have a smaller skin friction coefficient than a turbulent boundary layer?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

For a particular Reynolds number, I was wondering whether a laminar boundary layer is always preferable in terms of skin friction. So I looked towards the equations:

Blasius, laminar:
$$
C_{fl} = \frac{0.664}{\sqrt{Re}}
$$

Prandtl, turbulent:
$$
C_{ft} = \frac{0.027}{Re^\frac{1}{7}}
$$

For High reynolds (>1e4) this is obviously the case, a laminar boundary layer will always have a lower friction coefficient ($C_{ft} \gt C_{fl}$). However at values lower than 1e3; $C_{ft} \lt C_{fl}$.

So my question is this: is there a situation where a turbulent boundary layer induced early will result in reduced surface friction than its laminar counterpart? If so, is this a practical thing to achieve, or is it near impossible?

Comment: Those approximations are meant to be used within the limits in which they are valid.

Comment: Take a look at the work of B.S. Stratford and how the turbulent boundary layer can be caused to separate with *zero* skin friction...

Comment: Turbulent boundary layers generate always more drag than laminar boundary layers, so a longer turbulent boundary layer will always give more drag than a shorter one. Or is the question actually if: "is there a situation where a turbulent boundary layer induced early will result in reduced **total drag** than its laminar counterpart"? In that case the answer is surprisingly yes